# How can I upload and edit pdf in react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, react-hooks, node-modules

I want to upload a pdf in react app and view it in the application. I figured I can upload the file easily through node JS. But I am confused How to view and edit [adding page, deleting page] the pdf on a webpage?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [React PDF library](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/react/)